# Pass parameters to Liquibase Gradle Plugin configuration in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, arguments, liquibase, gradle-plugin

My current Spring Boot project is set up with Gradle and the Liquibase Gradle plugin.

We have a somewhat wacky implementation of database migrations, starting with a task that fires up a Spring Boot application which reads our entity models and writes them into a "current schema" in the database, and then performs a diff against the actual schema to create changelogs.

I want to configure the plugin in such a way that I can create an IntelliJ IDEA run configuration which passes database credentials to the task.

From the `build.grade`:

```
task createCurrentSchema(type: BootRunTask) {
    doFirst() {
        main = 'com.application.util.migration.CreateCurrentSchemaApplication'
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile 'path/to/db.changelog-current.xml'
            url 'db:protocol://host:post/actual_db_name'
            username <get from args>
            password <get from args>
            referenceUrl 'db:protocol://host:port/current_schema_db_name'
            referenceUsername <get from args>
            referencePassword <get from args>
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried various approaches:

- Pass credentials as VM options

  - `-Dspring.datasource.password`
  - `-Dliquibase.password`
  - `-Dpassword`
- Pass credentials as Arguments

  - `-Pspring.datasource.password`
  - `-Ppassword`
  - `-PliquibasePassword`
- Load data from configuration file

None of these approaches work.

I've checked existing [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620287/passing-parameter-and-value-to-gradle-liquibase-plugin) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347311/pass-liquibase-parameters-to-gradle-liquibase-update-task) to my problem on the topic of the Liquibase Gradle plugin.

Since the task fires up a Spring Boot application, I could run it with an attached debugger in IntelliJ IDEA and observed that **no** arguments are being passed at all, no matter how I setup the run configuration.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Were you able to fix it? What is the actual piece of code that represents <get from args> in your gradle file?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't solve the problem until I was pulled from the project, sorry. `<get from args>` referred to (secret) arguments I would have passed via CLI to run the Gradle script.